# Prepare Audio File for Sending to TensorFlow Model Server

Tags: tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow 2.4.1 and have a working script that classifies audio files.  It is pretty much copy/paste from the examples and works well.  I now want to send an audio file to Model Server for prediction.

I am stuck and how to get the audio into the json message.   I am new to TensorFlow and Python so am probably missing something basic.

Full code: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2089884

Where I try to use an existing dataset (of wrong type) to be the data:

```
data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": train_ds.batch(3).tolist()})
```

In this case the error is:

```
Saved model:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xmits_train", line 361, in <module>
    data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": train_ds.batch(3).tolist()})
AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

What I don't see he how to get BatchDataset into a structure that will be correct for ".tolist".  Of course I may need to use a different starting structure as well.

In the script I have tried all the structures that hold the audio and none can directly be used.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to utilize the test_audio data structure.   To encode the first few requests into json:

```
data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": test_audio[0:3].tolist()})
```

There may be ways to utilize the other data structures but this addresses the question.